# Guitar Action for practicing and learning

Tags: electric-guitar, practice, action

I know for certain that a lower action on a guitar makes playing easier, but does having a high action makes you more skilled by overcoming the extra difficulty or is it just an inconvenience?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The benefits of higher action go to lack of buzz. You can pick harder, which is nice for certain musics. I think it helps harmonics a little. I suppose there's some "You gotta want it, Rocky!" aspects, but really, yeah, high action is mostly something that'll keep beginners from moving forward.

Comment: I think it also depends on where on the fretboard you're playing. The lower down (like metal) it is, I think higher action becomes less of a problem. (lets you pick hard, reduces buzz for the open chords, etc)

Comment: I agree with your "depends" point, but I think high action is easier in the top five frets, where the strings get closer to the fretboard because you're near the nut, so thick-string high-action dreadnoughts are the standard heavy-strumming bluegrass style. 

Or, am I restating your point while thinking I disagree?

Comment: *Abnormally* high action can make playing difficult. But, within certain parameters, action up to individual player preference. On acoustic, I find higher action translates into slightly deeper tone. Lower action also makes the guitar slightly easier to play (although not as much as switching to lighter strings).

Comment: I do remember my first guitar, which had such a bad bend in the body that the strings were nearly an inch off the fretboard by the 17th fret. Got my finger strength up a lot - so much so that I found it really easy to barre chords when I got my first electric :-)

Comment: @VarLogRant, I think we're agreeing

Comment: I would not credit a lack of buzz to a higher action. While high action eliminates buzzing, a properly set up guitar will not buzz. All of my stuff is set to the lowest possible action. The individual players touch can do a lot to cause buzzing if you're not used to playing on a lower action setup as well.

Comment: @Tony, I'm 90% with you. Buzz is the sound of strings vibrating against frets, and you can get fairly low action without getting near that problem. High action beyond that point is either someone wanting to play a dobro without the high nut or someone not caring about the instrument. But, while you carve divots into your fingertips pushing down all that way, at least there won't be any buzz. That's the only possible benefit of the too-high action you often see on intro-level guitars.